# How to access files in the Hololens 3D object Folder

Tags: c#, hololens

I am working on an app that uses Trilib to load 3D models.  Currently the app works in Unity, and any fbx file in the PC 3D models folder is available to load in the HoloLens through remote holographic.. When I build the app and deploy to the HL I am unable to see any files.  I already set the permissions to the 3D Objects folder..

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Experimental.UI;
using TMPro;
using TriLib;

#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
#endif

#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

namespace HololensProject {

    public class HModelLoader : SingletonBehaviour<HModelLoader> {

        [Header("UI")]
        [SerializeField] private Transform m_content;
        [SerializeField] private ScrollingObjectCollection m_scrollingCollection;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject m_textButtonPrefab;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshPro m_currentPathTMP;

        [Header("Model Load")]
        [SerializeField] private Transform m_modelLoadArea;
        [SerializeField] private RuntimeAnimatorController m_runtimeAnimatorController;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject m_modelComponentPrefab;

        [SerializeField, HideInInspector] private byte[] m_defaultModelData;
        private static string[] m_directoryFiles;

        void Start() {
            m_content.gameObject.GetChilds().Destroy();
            m_scrollingCollection.UpdateCollection();

            StartCoroutine(ListModels());
        }

        IEnumerator LoadModels() {
            var loaded = false;

#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
            var modelData = m_defaultModelData;

            Task.Run(async () => {
                if (await KnownFolders.Objects3D.TryGetItemAsync("molecule_default.fbx") == null) {
                    var defaultModel = await KnownFolders.Objects3D.CreateFileAsync("molecule_default.fbx");
                    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(defaultModel, modelData);
                }

                var allModels = await KnownFolders.Objects3D.GetFilesAsync();

                Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke(() => {
                    m_currentPathTMP.text = KnownFolders.Objects3D.Path.Replace(@"\", "/");
                    m_directoryFiles = allModels.Where(f => f.FileType.ToLower() == ".fbx").Select(f => f.Path).ToArray();
                });
            });
#else
            var userPath = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            var objects3DPath = Path.Combine(userPath, "3D Objects");

            Directory.CreateDirectory(objects3DPath);

            if (!File.Exists(objects3DPath + "/molecule_default.fbx"))
                File.WriteAllBytes(objects3DPath + "/molecule_default.fbx", m_defaultModelData);

            m_currentPathTMP.text = objects3DPath.Replace(@"\", "/");
            m_directoryFiles = new DirectoryInfo(objects3DPath).GetFiles().Where(f => f.Extension.ToLower() == ".fbx").Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
            loaded = true;
#endif
            while (!loaded) 
                yield return null;
        }

        IEnumerator ListModels() {
            yield return LoadModels();

            if (m_directoryFiles.Length == 0)
                yield break;

            for (var i = 0; i < m_directoryFiles.Length; i++) {
                var button = Instantiate(m_textButtonPrefab, m_content).GetComponent<Interactable>();
                var tmp = button.transform.Find("IconAndText/TextMeshPro").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
                var filePath = m_directoryFiles[i];

                tmp.text = Path.GetFileName(m_directoryFiles[i]);

                button.OnClick.AddListener(() => {
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
                    Task.Run(async () => {
                        if (await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath) != null)
                            Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke(() => LoadModel(filePath, Instantiate(Instance.m_modelComponentPrefab)));
                    });
#else
                    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                        return;

                    LoadModel(filePath, Instantiate(Instance.m_modelComponentPrefab));
#endif
                });
            }

            m_scrollingCollection.UpdateCollection();
        }

        static void LoadModel(string modelPath, GameObject wrapperGameObject) {
            using (var assetLoaderAsync = new AssetLoaderAsync()) {
                var assetLoaderOptions = AssetLoaderOptions.CreateInstance();

                assetLoaderOptions.UseLegacyAnimations = false;
                assetLoaderOptions.AnimatorController = Instance.m_runtimeAnimatorController;

                var thread = assetLoaderAsync.LoadFromFile(modelPath, assetLoaderOptions, null, delegate (GameObject loadedModel) {
                    loadedModel.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(modelPath);
                    loadedModel.transform.SetParent(wrapperGameObject.transform);
                    wrapperGameObject.transform.SetParent(Instance.m_modelLoadArea);

                    var c = loadedModel.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

                    foreach (var x in c)
                        x.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();

                    var x1 = wrapperGameObject.GetComponent<Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Experimental.UI.BoundsControl.BoundsControl>();
                    var x2 = wrapperGameObject.GetComponent<ManipulationHandler>();

                    x1.BoundsOverride = c.FirstOrDefault().GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
                    x1.Awake();
                    x2.Awake();

                    wrapperGameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.1f, .1f, .1f);
                });
            }
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        [Header("Editor")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject m_defaultTestModel;

        void OnValidate() {
            if (m_defaultTestModel && (null != m_defaultModelData || m_defaultModelData.Length == 0)) {
                var modelPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(m_defaultTestModel);
                m_defaultModelData = File.ReadAllBytes(modelPath);
            }
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­-­­­­1­­ ­for not specifying language

Answer (score 0):

Although you can get a reference of the file in the Object3D Library through [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile?view=winrt-18362) Class, you cannot directly access the files in the Library folder through the path.

But you can read file data using memory as a backing store, and then call [TriLib.AssetLoaderAsync.LoadFromMemory()](https://ricardoreis.net/trilib/manual/html/class_tri_lib_1_1_asset_loader_async.html#ae5f1719337a0e5ed96c47580b5a2990e) to load the data from memory.

First, you need to call [IStorageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.windowsruntimestorageextensions.openstreamforreadasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to retrieves a stream for reading from the StorageFile instance. Then call [CopyTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Stream_CopyTo_System_IO_Stream_) method of this instance to copy the bytes to another [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netcore-3.1) instance, and finally use its [ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=netcore-3.1) method to convert it to byte[],

After these steps, you will get a byte [] class data, which can be used as a parameter to call [TriLib.AssetLoaderAsync.LoadFromMemory()](https://ricardoreis.net/trilib/manual/html/class_tri_lib_1_1_asset_loader_async.html#ae5f1719337a0e5ed96c47580b5a2990e)

Comment: Would you be able to give me a hand with the code ? I am not a developer.. Thanks Hernando..

Comment: @CarlosArrieta I'd recommend you to work with the team to finish the modification, we are willing to help you if you have specific coding issues with an exception.